# Junit Powermock issue with mocking a static method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

This is the first time I am experimenting with JUnit and somehow landed to this problem.

Following is the structure of the class that I have to test:

```
public class ClassA extends AbstractClassA {

        @Override
    public java.lang.AutoCloseable createInstance() {
        ClassC provider = new ClassC();
        ...
        /*Following line is the problematic area - Class A invoking the static method of Class B with some parameters*/
        ClassB.init(getPort(),getConnectorUsername(),getConnectorPassword(),schemaRegistry,schemaContextFactory,getDefaultRequestTimeoutMillis(),bundleContext,domBroker,bindingBroker,getClientDispatcherDependency());
        return provider;
    }
```

I am writing a junit test case for testing createInstance as follows:

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({ClassB.class,
                     ClassA.class})
    public class ClassATest {

        @Test
        public void testCreateInstance() throws Exception {
            // configure mocks
            DependencyResolver dependencyResolver = mock(DependencyResolver.class);
            BindingAwareBroker bindingAwareBroker = mock(BindingAwareBroker.class);

            when(dependencyResolver.resolveInstance(eq(BindingAwareBroker.class), any(ObjectName.class), any(JmxAttribute.class))).thenReturn(bindingAwareBroker);

            // create instance of module with injected mocks
            ClassA module = new ClassA(mock(ModuleIdentifier.class), dependencyResolver);

            // Approach 1 to - Mock the ClassB' static method, stub init() to return 
            //PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassB.class);
            //PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ClassB.class, "init", anyInt(), anyString(), anyString(), any(SchemaSourceRegistry.class), any(SchemaContextFactory.class), anyLong(), 
            //      any(BundleContext.class), any(Broker.class), any(BindingAwareBroker.class), any(NetconfClientDispatcher.class));

            /* Approach 2 to - Mock the ClassB' static method, stub init() to return 
            //PowerMockito.spy(ClassB.class);
            //PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ClassB.class);
            //ClassB.init(anyInt(), anyString(), anyString(), any(SchemaSourceRegistry.class), any(SchemaContextFactory.class), anyLong(), 
            //      any(BundleContext.class), any(Broker.class), any(BindingAwareBroker.class), any(NetconfClientDispatcher.class));*/

            // getInstance calls resolveInstance to get the broker dependency and then calls createInstance
            AutoCloseable closeable = module.getInstance();


        }
    }
```

My issue is how to do this correctly. module.createInstance is raising a NUll Pointer exception at the point where ClassB.init is called in the method. 
If I comment the ClassB.init method from Class.createInstance the test passes which means that I am not mocking it correctly.

I used 2 approaches for mocking as the init is a static method, but none of them is working.

Can someone point to me with the root cause of this issue or how to handle this kind of problem while writing JUnit Tests?

Comment: This is not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please spend some time and make your code represent **only** the issue. Currently it has a lot of noise, which makes it hard to understand what you want, without some amount of effort.

Comment: @user3707125 Updated

Comment: @SahilShah, I can probably help you but I need some more information. Show me where AutoCloseable.getInstance() is calling ClassB.init(). Also paste the error message of the null pointer exception.

Comment: @Lencalot module.getInstance() first calls resolveInstance and then calls createInstance. Even module.createInstance() fetches the same result. I will share the error log. Can you comment that the approach to mock ClassB.init() is correct. Many thanks for raising the hope to resolve this.

Comment: @Lencalot testCreateInstance(org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.callhome.impl.rev141210.ClassATest)  Time elapsed: 0.297 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.callhome.impl.rev141210.ClassA.createInstance(ClassA.java:44)
 at org.opendaylight.controller.config.spi.AbstractModule.getInstance(AbstractClassA.java:74)
 at org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.params.xml.ns.yang.callhome.impl.rev141210.ClassATest.testCreateInstance(ClassATest.java:72)

Comment: @Lencalot http://pastebin.com/9hVu5jp6 This is the stack trace. Exception is raised when **Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606** is reached and that too when Method.Class -> line 606: return ma.invoke(obj, args); is executed. I am suspecting the Class B is not mocked correctly.

Comment: @SahilShah Please edit your post, include code that calls ClassB.init(). (and any code in that method uses/calls ClassB or the object returned from ClassB.init().)

Comment: @Lencalot ClassB.init() is called by the ClassC.createInstance() method as already included in the code. ClassC.init() does not return any object, it is a void method used to initialise a ClassC with the parameters available here. In the test case we can do module.createInstance() also, but issue is the null pointer exception getting raised.

Comment: @SahilShah I am unable to help you with the information provided. If you would like me to help you with this issue further (but do not want to post your code on here) You can feel free to send me an email with the information. I need the following classes to help you further: 

I need all of Class A, Class B, and Class C. (if its sensitive I won't use any of it, I'm only going to try and help. But you can remove anything that pretty much isn't *Instance) My email is LenaclotP@gmail.com.

I'm about 90% sure you are not mocking something that needs to be mocked and or instantiated.

Comment: This is the same issue, I am also facing... please someone provide solution to it...